# R highcharter multiple column chart with points

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to draw a chart with multiple columns and points in each column like this:
[image]

Please help

```
tb_to_chart <- data.frame(A = c(3, 4, 2),
                          B = c(4, 2, 3)
                          )
targets <- c(1, 3)
row.names(tb_to_chart) <- c("2022", "2023", "2024")
chart <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = row.names(tb_to_chart))

for(i in 1:ncol(tb_to_chart)){
  chart <- chart %>%
    hc_add_series(tb_to_chart[,i], name = names(tb_to_chart)[i])
}


chart <- chart %>%
  hc_add_series(targets, type = "scatter", name = "target", color = "red") ###  Wrong!!!

chart
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an option to add a scatter series of target values that pertain to each series, in this case "A" / "B".

Rather than using a for loop to add each series. I pivoted `tb_to_chart` from wide to long. Then you can use the group argument in `hcaes`.

I then created a targets data frame to include the target values for each field along with the year.

By default the scatter series will align to the center position. So you need to use `pointPlacement` in order for them to align to the grouped series.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tb_to_chart <- data.frame(A = c(3, 4, 2),
                          B = c(4, 2, 3),
                          Year = c("2022", "2023", "2024"))

targets_df = data.frame(targets_A = c(rep(1,3)), 
                        targets_B = c(rep(3,3)),
                        Year = c("2022", "2023", "2024"))

tb_to_chart = tb_to_chart %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("A","B"))

highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", categories = unique(tb_to_chart$Year)) %>%
  hc_add_series(tb_to_chart, hcaes(x = Year, y = value, group = name), type = "column") %>%
  hc_add_series(targets_df, hcaes(x = Year, y = targets_A), type = "scatter", color = "red", pointPlacement = -.15, name = "A Targets") %>%
  hc_add_series(targets_df, hcaes(x = Year, y = targets_B), type = "scatter", color = "red", pointPlacement = .15, name = "B Targets",
                marker = list(symbol = "circle")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE, split = FALSE)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you! How du you calc pointPlacement? I ask because I have multiple columns A, B, C, D...

Comment: 0                                   # 1;
-0.15, 0.15                         # 2;
-0.2, 0, 0.2                        # 3;
-0.225, -0.075, 0.075, 0.225        # 4

Comment: Like pointPlacement <- calc_pointPlacement(ncol(tb_to_chart ))?

Comment: Hmm I'm having difficulty trying to come up with a function to accurately give the pointPlacement for any number of groups. I would pose that question in the mathematics stackexchange.